# Complex integral along different curves.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the integral of the complex function $f(z)$ = 1/$(1-z)^3$ along three different curves. 
i. along a circle centered at 0 of radius 1/2
ii. along a circle centered at 1 of radius 1/2
iii. along a circle centered at -1 of radius 1/2.

I know there's a singularity at 1. And the first and third curve does not enclose it. So the function is holomorphic and Cauchy's theorem applies to give that the integral is 0. For second curve, the center itself is the singularity. I'm not sure how to proceed for it. Also, am I correct about 1st and 3rd curve?
Any help with these integrals is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** the integral is $2i\pi\cdot \operatorname{Res}(f,1)$

Comment: Thanks. So the residue and hence the integral is 0. Am I correct in parts 1 and 3 please?

Comment: Yes, you're right about 1 and 3

Comment: @Marwalix You mean the integral along the second path which is alone among the three ones, and this must be stressed, to include the singularity **inside** the contour.

Comment: You're absolutely right @JeanMarie

Answer (score 0):

You can say $z=1+1/2e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ also $dz=1/2ie^{it}dt$
$$\int f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(-1/2e^{it})^3}1/2ie^{it}dt=\int_0^{2\pi}-4ie^{-2it}dt=2e^{-2it}|_0^{2\pi}=0$$